# reverse polish notation calculator in c

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am programming a rnp calculator in c. I have 2 problems:

1. Everything works fine, when I write something like 3 a 3 +. I get the right solution and my programm ignores the a(which is how it should be). But by typing only a for instance I get a segmentation fault.
2. I get a segmentation fault too, when I type in to much operators, for instance 3 5 + +.

I think the problem is in "void process"...

```
typedef struct _stack stack;
typedef struct _stack_element stack_element;

struct _stack {
    stack_element* top;
};

struct _stack_element {
    stack_element* next;
    float value;
};
```

```
void stack_push(stack* astack, float value)
{
    stack_element *elem1 = (stack_element *) malloc(sizeof(stack_element));
    
    elem1->value = value;
    elem1->next = astack->top;
    astack->top = elem1;
}
```

```
float stack_pop(stack* astack)
{
    float cur;

    if (astack == NULL) {
        cur = NAN;
    }
    else {
        cur = astack->top->value;
        stack_element *nxt = astack->top->next;
        free(astack->top);
        astack->top = nxt;
        
    }
    return cur;
}
```

```
void process(stack* astack, char* token)
{
if(is_number(token) == 1) {
    float number = atof(token);
    stack_push(astack, number);
    }
    else if (is_add(token) == 1) {
    float number1 = stack_pop(astack);
    float number2 = stack_pop(astack);
    stack_push(astack, (number1 + number2)); 
    }
    else if(is_sub(token) == 1) {
    float number1 = stack_pop(astack);
    float number2 = stack_pop(astack);
    stack_push(astack, (number2 - number1));
    }
    else if(is_mult(token) == 1) {
    float number1 = stack_pop(astack);
    float number2 = stack_pop(astack);
    stack_push(astack, (number1 * number2));
    }

    printf("\n<Logik fehlt!>\n");
    return;
```

```
stack* create_stack() {
    /* HIER implementieren */
    stack *newstack = (stack *) calloc(1, sizeof(stack));
    newstack->top = NULL;

    return newstack;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `stack_pop` function will set `astack->top` to a null pointer after you have popped your last element from the stack.

But you never check for that, you never check for an empty stack.

Modify the condition checking for `astack` being a null pointer to also check for an empty stack:

```
if (astack == NULL || astack->top == NULL)
```